# Q: Docker: How to make several portranges available to ouside

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I just started playing around with Docker and was able to setup a docker image using Ubuntu 14.03 / LXDE / VNC which works fine since I can connect from outside to the VNC server.

Now I am trying to understand the Networking of Docker but it seems I am completely lost. Since I had to forward the port for VNC already it seems that no further ports could be forwarded?

Assuming I have an application running under Wine which requires several portranges, how to achieve that? Does it mean that I would need to create a further container running the Wine application on top of the base image?

Comment: What specifically about the `-p` option is confusing you?

Comment: As a experienced linux user it would never come to my mind that the same parameter (-p) is allowed many times in one single command. So I think the confusion is not far away from reality.

Comment: My question was a legitimate one. I figured you'd discovered `-p` but wasn't sure why it wasn't working for you. Now I understand :-) Note that specifying options multiple times does have precedent; often times, `-vvv` is more verbose than `-v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `-p` option as often as you want

ie `-p 8080-8085:8080-8085 -p 1234:1234 -p 9000-9005:9000-9005`

Comment: @deterministicFail Please be patient. There is a 15-minute delay before an answer can be accepted.